# Unknown module(s) in QT: axcontainer

Tags: c++, qt, qaxwidget

Well I can't make qt recognize axcontainer, I need to use a QAxWidget to display a .doc but I'm struggling with this. Here is my .pro

```
QT += core gui
QT += axcontainer

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Archivador
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
    InterfazArchivador.cpp

HEADERS  += InterfazArchivador.h

FORMS    += InterfazArchivador.ui
```

and here where I need the QAxWidget

```
#include "InterfazArchivador.h"
#include "ui_InterfazArchivador.h"
#include <QAxWidget>

InterfazArchivador::InterfazArchivador(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::InterfazArchivador)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QAxWidget* Document= new QAxWidget ("Word", this-> ui-> textEdit);
    Document-> setGeometry (QRect (10, 10, 612, 481));
    Document->setControl ("D:\\Qt\\Project\\SinceThen.doc");
    Document-> show ()
}
```

I'm using QT version 5.4 and I've tried with CONFIG += axcontainer but the same, did I have to install something

Comment: I can't build the project because Unknown module(s) in QT: axcontainer Qt don't recognize axcontainer

Comment: what do you have in mkspecs\modules folder? mine is at ... Qt\5.4.0\5.4\msvc2013_opengl\mkspecs\modules Do you have qt_lib_axbase.pri etc?

Comment: I've checked and no I dont have qt_lib_axbase.pri do I need  to install it? I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I'm working under linux so the directory isn't the same

Comment: ah well. you can use these stuff in windows only...

Comment: Qt is not a substitution to Windows COM yet and QAxObject is just a Qt convenience for Windows. I like this thread.